# Python XML file creation usnig a loop and assignig values to subelements

Tags: python, xml, assign

I'm using xml.etree.ElementTree module with Python 3.6 to create an XML file with dozens of subelements. What I'm aiming for should look like this:

```
<shots>
    <shot id="0">
    <Audio_Channels>2</Audio_Channels>
    <Audio_File>testhq12.mov</Audio_File>
    <Audio_Fps>Unspecified</Audio_Fps>
    ...
    <Type>C</Type>
    <Width>4096</Width>
    <shot/>
    <shot id="1">
    ....
</shots>
```

And so far I've been using the following code to create this structure but it gets very ugly when theres a lot of 'sub-fields' to add

```
_audio_channels = Element('Audio_Channels')
shot.append(_audio_channels)
_audio_channels.text = str(audio_channels_data)

_audio_file = Element('Audio_File')
shot.append(_audio_file)
_audio_file.text = str(audio_file_data)
.
.
.
```

And so I've tried to simplify it with a loop looking somewhat like this:

```
fields = ['Audio_Channels', 'Audio_File', 'Audio_Fps', ...]
for k in fields:
    prop = Element(k)
    shot.append(prop)
```

But I have no idea how to assing any text to them later on using only elements from fields list as sort of keys?
Tried this but it's not working

```
shot.insert(str(audio_file_data), 'Audio_File')
```

Comment: Can you provide short examples of what `audio_channels_data`, `audio_file_data` and (I assume) `audio_fps_data` look like?

Comment: In the following order: 2, 'testhq12.mov', 'Unspecified'. So an int, string, string

Comment: Basically I don't know what method to use to assign the values above after "for k in fields" loop is finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undertand correctly what you are after, try something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
fields = ['Audio_Channels', 'Audio_File', 'Audio_Fps']
dats = [ 2,'testhq12.mov', 'Unspecified']

shots = ET.Element('shots')
shot = ET.SubElement(shots, 'shot')
for f, d in zip(fields,dats):
    elem = ET.Element(f)
    elem.text=str(d)
    shot.append(elem)
```

The output should look something like:

```
<shots>
   <shot>
      <Audio_Channels>2</Audio_Channels>
      <Audio_File>testhq12.mov</Audio_File>
      <Audio_Fps>Unspecified</Audio_Fps>
   </shot>
</shots>
```